# GWT, I need a way to fit a scrollpanel to the current size of A SplitLayoutPanel

Tags: java, gwt, layout

i know there is some trouble taking LayoutPanels together with panels like ScrollPanel. Is it even possible to fit a scrollpanel to the current size of a SplitLayoutPanel? For example:

```
   SplitLayoutPanel p = new SplitLayoutPanel(5) 
   ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel 

  p.addWest(someOtherPanel); 
  p.add(sp);
```

Thanks in advance. A way i could probably do it is to override onResize method. However i am not sure if there is a better solution already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollPanel implements RequiresResize. LayoutPanel (of any type) implements ProvidesResize. They work really nice together but only if a ScrollPanel is the direct child and only widget in a layer of LayoutPanel. In such cases ScrollPanel will take its size from the size of a layer that it was added to.

Once you add another widget to the same layer where ScrollPanel is, you break this chain of ProvidesResize - RequiresResize widgets. Now a ScrollPanel does not know from where to take its size, so it will never start to scroll.

In your use case, if you want this chain to continue, you need to add a VerticalPanel to the west region of SplitLayoutPanel. Then you add your someOtherPanel to one cell and ScrollPanel to the other cell of your VerticalPanel.

Alternatively, you can simply set position:absolute, top:0 on your someOtherPanel and use a regular FlowPanel or HTMLPanel instead of ScrollPanel with overflow:auto style.

Comment: Thanks I used a FlowPanel with its overlow set to auto and it worked just fine!